# Ruby curb (libcurl): testing for time-out in GET request

Tags: ruby, timeout, libcurl, curb

Using `curb` gem (https://github.com/taf2/curb) to `GET` from a REST API.

```
  resp = Curl.get("http://someurl.com/users.json") do |http|
    http.headers["API-Key"] = ENV["API_KEY"]
  end
  # do stuff with resp.body_str
```

I've started encountering occasional time-outs with the `Curl.get`.

Would like to add logic where I try to `GET`: if the request times out, we try it again, i.e.

```
loop do
  resp = Curl.get("http://someurl.com/users.json") do |http|
    http.headers["API-Key"] = ENV["API_KEY"]
  end

  # test result of Curl.get
  # if time-out, then then try again
end
```

Haven't been able to find/figure out how to test for a time-out result.

What am I missing?

**UPDATED**: added exception details

```
Curl::Err::TimeoutError: Timeout was reached
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/curb-0.9.3/lib/curl/easy.rb:73:in `perform'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/curb-0.9.3/lib/curl.rb:17:in `http'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/curb-0.9.3/lib/curl.rb:17:in `http'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/curb-0.9.3/lib/curl.rb:22:in `get'
/app/lib/tasks/redmine.rake:307:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Comment: What do you see on the terminal when it times out?  In other words, what do you see that tells you that it timed out?  I believe the question is more precisely asked as "what does Curl.get do when a timeout occurs?".  It probably raises an exception, but may just return a special value.  I just looked through the source code for a few minutes and could not find out which.  If it raises an error, then rescue its error class only, not all errors, and do the processing there. You could do a `rescue; binding.pry; end` to inspect the errors.

Comment: Thanks @KeithBennett I've added the exception output. Ok, great suggesetion: if I put the `rescue` directly under the `Curl.get` to catch that exception, that's the appropriate scope?

Comment: Yes.  I've offered an answer below with a sample implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the general idea of the rescue approach I mentioned in my comment:

```
loop do
  begin
    resp = Curl.get("http://someurl.com/users.json") do |http|
        http.headers["API-Key"] = ENV["API_KEY"]
    end
    # process successful response here
  rescue Curl::Err::TimeoutError
      # process error here
  end
end
```

You would then need to modify this to do the retries.  Here is 1 implementation (not tested though):

```
# Returns the response on success, nil on TimeoutError
def get1(url)
  begin
    Curl.get(url) do |http|
      http.headers["API-Key"] = ENV["API_KEY"]
    end
  rescue Curl::Err::TimeoutError
    nil
  end
end


# Returns the response on success, nil on TimeoutErrors after all retry_count attempts.
def get_with_retries(url, retry_count)
  retry_count.times do
    result = get1(url)
    return result if result
  end
  nil
end


response = get_with_retries("http://someurl.com/users.json", 3)
if response
  # handle success
else
  # handle timeout failure
end
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also do it in block

```
def handle_timeouts
   begin
     yield
   rescue Curl::Err::TimeoutError
     retry
   end
end

handle_timeouts do
  resp = Curl.get("http://someurl.com/users.json") do |http|
    http.headers["API-Key"] = ENV["API_KEY"]
  end
end
```